# Code First not creating tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

So I'm using Entity Framework Code First to create tables in an existing remote SQL Server database and when I do:

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration Inital
Update-Database
```

No tables are created whatsoever. This is my DbContext:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using TrabalhoDefinitivo.Models;
using TrabalhoDefinitivo.ViewModels;

namespace TrabalhoDefinitivo.DAL
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AlbumType> AlbumTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SaleAlbum> SaleAlbums { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I tried adding a new connection string manuall in Web.config with this:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Data Source=gandalf.dei.isep.ipp.pt\sqlexpress;
            Initial Catalog=xxxx;
            User ID=xxxx;
            Password=xxxx"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

After that I added a new connection in server explorer, testing it with success and repeated step one. No tables again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what did the generated migration file look like?

Comment: Not sure but I think you have to use the name of your connectionstring: public ApplicationDbContext() : base("name=ApplicationServices"). And where did you place your mapping?

Comment: Yeah I'm an idiot. When I changed the name it worked like a charm.

Comment: You can see what is happening by adding -Verbose to the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change ApplicationDbContext cnstructor to

```
 public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("ApplicationServices")
        {
        }
```

That way you will use the Connection string from your Web.config

Comment: Ok, I'm back, that was indeed the issue. Love you.